How to override AMCharts 5 Treemap drilldown feature to allow click action to external link
We're currently trying to use the AMCharts 5 Treemap to create a visualization that, when clicked, navigates to external page. We have a treemap of different industries, and Drupal pages set up for each of those industries. However, the Treemap has a built in drilldown feature, which seems to be overriding the desired click action.
We're trying to get the user routed to the relevant page using code essentially the same as this, which we're using successfully for a map:
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on('click', (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.url) {
    window.location.href = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.url;
  }
});

This setup seems to have worked fine for other charts types, but the issue we're running into with the treemap, specifically, is that the drilldown feature of the chart itself seems to be overriding the click action, even if it isn't being used.
Any thoughts on how we can override the drilldown and get the click to send the user to an external link?
